# If $f(x) + g(y)$ is constant, are $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ both constants too?

Tags: functions

$x$ and $y$ are two **independent variables**. My intuition tells me that if $x$ and $y$ are independent and $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ sum up to give a constant value, then those two functions should be constant on their own. What I need is a supporting proof or rather a approach to this dilemma in a mathematical way.

$f(x)$ depends on $x$ only and $g(y)$ depends on $y$ only.

Comment: How about $f(x)=x-y+c$ and $g(y)=y-x+c$?

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write $g(y)$, not $g(x)$. And why did you tag this as `linear-algebra`?

Comment: What about $x^2+C$ and $-x^2+D$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes I meant to write $g(y)$. Thanks

Comment: @crskhr provided : $f(x)$ depends on only $x$ and $g(y)$ depends on only $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is not constant. Then there are $x_1,x_2\in D_f$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Now, take $y_0\in D_g$. Then$$f(x_1)+g(y_0)=f(x_2)+g(y_0),$$which is impossible, since $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

The same argument proves that $g$ is constant.